# Laravel api resources only queried data

Tags: laravel

As per [json:api](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sparse-fieldsets) standards a client can request that an endpoint return only specific fields in the response, so I have this code in my controller:

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $members = Member::query();

    if ($request->query('fields')) {
        $members->select($request->query('fields'));
    }

    return MemberResource::collection($members->paginate());
}
```

but since the resource has all fields it will still return the other fields with `null` values.

I am looking for a clean way to **still use api resources** but getting only the queried fields, similar to `$this->whenloaded()` something like `$this->whenQueried()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enhanced version of Yossel's answer.

```php
public function whenExists($field, $value = null)
{
  return $this->when(array_key_exists($field, $this->resource->toArray()), $value ?? $this->$field);
}
```

this way I can reuse the field as the value

```php
"first_name" => $this->whenExists("first_name"),
```

instead of

```php
"first_name" => $this->whenExists("first_name", $this->first_name),
```